# How to make multiple subquery in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, subquery, multiple-select

I am working with PHP and Laravel 6 and I need to query multiple subqueries. The subquerys are on the same table and I can't do it with a join (or I can't think of a way to do it).

I need to do this query:

> select t.nombre, t.anio, (select v.value form Valor v where
> v.id=t.tipo) as tipo, (select v.value form Valor v where
> v.id=t.centro) as centro from Titulo

I have tried to do something like that but it doesn't work:

```php
$query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

$titulos = DB::table('titulo as t')
    ->select('t.nombre','t.anio')
    ->DB::raw('(select v.value from Valor v where t.tipo = v.id) as tipo'))
    ->paginate(7);
```

Could you help me?

Thank you very much, I read you!

Comment: Laravel has a good ORM you can use for relations.  HasOne, HasMany, BelongsTo, etc.

Comment: The tables would not be related. The Value table is a table that in the database I do not have related to any other, it is an auxiliary table that groups data of many types and that the rest of the tables make use of.

Comment: instead of the `->DB::raw()` you need to write `->selectRaw()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the [`selectSub`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectSub) function

```
$query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

$titulos = DB::table('titulo as t')

    ->select('t.nombre','t.anio')

    ->selectSub(function ($query) {
        $query->from('Valor')
            ->whereColumn('Valor.id', 'titulo.tipo')
            ->select('Valor.value')
            ->latest()
            ->take(1);
    }, 'tipo')

    ->selectSub(function ($query) {
        $query->from('Valor')
            ->whereColumn('Valor.id', 'titulo.centro')
            ->select('Valor.value')
            ->latest()
            ->take(1);
    }, 'centro')

    ->paginate(7);
```